# non-ASCII encoding in SQL and PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, encoding

I would like to retrieve a string with non-ASCII characters from PostgreSQL using this code:

```
            String query = "SELECT file_name FROM crm_files WHERE table_id = " + id + " AND table_name = '" + tableName + "'";
            Connection conn = getConnection();
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()) {
                fileName = rs.getString(1);
            }
            return fileName;
```

In PostgreSQL all characters are shown properly[image]

However when I run this code on Wildfly10, the fileName logged to the console
looks like this:[image]

And here is the file name, after download using servlet.

[image]

How to fix this code?

Comment: That sounds as if the console window can't display those characters (or the font selected for the console). Which operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what Wildfly10 is, but I'd say that your Java code needs to convert the string to the encoding it expects (see `java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder`).
Or you teach Wildfly10 to perform the conversion, if that is possible.